# Can this ruby method be refactored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

A `user` has multiple `libraries`, and each library has multiple `books`. I want to know if a user has a book in one of his libraries. I'm calling this method with: `current_user.has_book?(book)`:

```
def has_book?(book)
  retval = false
  libraries.each do |l|
    retval = true if l.books.include?(book)
  end
  return retval
end
```

Can my method be refactored?

Comment: For what purpose? What is your goal in the end? Shorter is not necessarily clearer, if clarity is your goal.

Comment: My purpose is to adopt and understand the "tips & tricks" of the langage that I use to produce a more maintainable code and stay in accordance with the common use. I don't want an ugly code nor 10 lines of code if I can do the job in 1 or 2.

Comment: In Ruby, you can always replace newlines with semicolons, so you can always do the job in 1 line: `def has_book?(book) retval = false; libraries.each do |l| retval = true if l.books.include?(book) end; return retval end`. That doesn't necessarily make it more maintainable, though. (Side note: I really don't understand the obsession with "fewer lines" or "one-liners".)

Comment: Maintainability and... duh... "idiomaticity"? I mean, your end goal is to have maintainable and idiomatic code. Then you need refactoring, apparently. Your latest edit seems to be addressing that.

Comment: I wonder why @Зелёный deleted his answer, it did seem to answer what this question is now, and it even improved performance drastically.

Comment: Do you often see this methodology to use a local variable retval then return it like in C in Ruby. Because I've never seen it yet so I was guessing this was not the "common use" and asked for clarification/refactoring. Plus, my main goal is not to reduce line, it's a plus if I can do both.

Comment: Based on your current version of this question, it seems like you are wanting to use the method called `any?`, which will return true if any are found.  This will alleviate the idea of having a "retval" (whatever that means, it doesn't seem to be an English word) variable to track some flag.

Comment: @vgoff it's a common variable name (at least in C) meaning "returned value". But yes, you are right about `any?`

Comment: I mentioned it due to your comment of "not wanting ugly code" and your other mention of the tips and tricks (I take that as idioms) of Ruby, not C.  Also, of course, you mention it in prior comments.   To clarify, yes, I am right on the retval, name it what it is for clarity (not technically what it is, but the idea it represents).  I suspect we could name "everything" that is returned "retval" and be done with the entire naming problem.  But that is a problem in itself.  It's Ruby, use good names. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why @Зелёный removed his answer but this was a good one IMO so I paste it here:

```
def has_book?(book)
  libraries.includes(:books)
           .where(books: {id: book.id})
           .any?
end
```

Comment: Side note: I personally try to avoid nested hashes in `where` since they rely on table names. An alternative is to use `merge` like so: `.merge(Book.where(id: book.id))`. This change makes no sense as-is, but allows you to swap the inner `where`-clause for a scope on `Book` class.

Answer (score 2):

```
def has_book?(book)
    libraries.any?{|lib| lib.books.include?book}
end
```

Pretty much the simplest i can imagine.
Not Nil safe though.

Answer (score 1):

```
def has_book?(book)
  libraries.map { |l| l.books.include?(book) }.any?
end
```

`map` turns collection of library objects into collection of bools, depending do they include the book, and `any?` returns `true` if any of the elements in the array is `true`.

this has fewer lines, but your original solution could be more efficient if you return `true` as soon as you find a library that contains the book.

```
def has_book?(book)
  libraries.each do |l|
    return true if l.books.include?(book)
  end
  return false
end
```

btw. both php and ruby appeared about the same time.

Comment: Your first snippet doesn't need `map` at all: you can use just `collection.any? { |element| element.whatever? }` This is just as efficient as the latter, since it breaks on first `true` encountered.

Comment: good point. thanks for correcting me. then `any?` with a block is the best way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be the most minified version, I can't see any way to minify it more:

```
def has_book?(a)c=false;libraries.each{|b|c=true if b.books.include?a};c end
```